# how to change loop with a Signal.SIGUSR1?

Tags: loops, signals, handler

I need help to implement a script that starts with a loop and when it receives a Signal (`SIGUSR1`), it will stop the current loop and enter in the next loop.
How can I achieve this?
This is what I'm working on.

```
import time
import signal
import os

def signal_handler(signum, stack):
   print("SIGNAL RECEIVED")
   while True:
       print("second loop")
       time.sleep(0.5)
signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, signal_handler)

while True:
       print("wait")
       time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're *working on* already does what you demand. However, you might want *the next loop* outside the signal handler:

```
import time
import signal

signal_received = 0
def signal_handler(signum, stack):
    global signal_received
    signal_received = 1
    print("SIGNAL RECEIVED")
signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, signal_handler)

while not signal_received:
    print("wait")
    time.sleep(0.5)
while True:
    print("second loop")
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

---

> switching between 2 different loops via SIGUSR1 AND SIGUSR2

```
import time
import signal

signal_received = 0
def signal_handler(signum, stack):
    global signal_received
    print("SIGNAL", signum, "RECEIVED")
    signal_received = [signal.SIGUSR2, signal.SIGUSR1].index(signum)
signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR2, signal_handler)

while True:
    if signal_received == 0:
        print("wait")
        time.sleep(0.5)
    elif signal_received == 1:
        print("second loop")
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: thanks a million. that looks much nicer!

`while signal_received == 0:

    print("wait")

    time.sleep(0.5)

while signal_received == 1:

    print("second loop")

    time.sleep(0.5)`

works as well.
now i wonder if  is possible to switch loops based on the different SIGUSR1 or SIGUSR2 received!
this is so cool!

Comment: You mean, go back to the first loop if SIGUSR2 is received?

Comment: actually, it would be ace to start with the first loop, and after that switching between 2 different loops via SIGUSR1 AND SIGUSR2. I will work on it

Comment: I added a variant with _switching between 2 different loops_ (or different branches of a loop); maybe you can use it for your work.

Comment: I had no idea of all this. It will be indeed useful and there is a lot of material for me to learn and try out. Your help has been much appreciated!